# Preencher dois objetos em um form jsf

Tags: jsf

Bom dia,

É possível preencher dois objetos diferentes no mesmo form?

Ex:

```
<p:inputText id="ordem" value="#{testeBean.objA.atributoA}" />

<p:inputText id="ordem2" value="#{testeBean.objB.atributoB}" />
```

To pegando o primeiro obj vem preenchido o segundo sempre vem null

estou trabalhando com jsf

Comment: Cara porque vc quer fazer isso?
Esses dois objetos tem algo haver entre sí?

Comment: cara deu certo aqui, sim esses objetos tem relação. 
Não teve mistério apenas direcionei o bean como mostrei no code de exemplo. Acho que tinha algum erro na injeção..

Comment: Minha pergunta se refere mais ao aspecto do design da classe, posta aí como são as duas classes